# "Object Expected" Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My code has started giving an "object expected" javascript error, though it was working well before. It is still working fine in another solution.

I have tried changing the contents of the rest of the code, and I am still getting the exception. The script giving the exception is the following:

```
< script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >
$(document).ready(function ()
{     
   ////code comes here
});
< /script >
```

Comment: What line is the exception on? unless you do not have jQuery loaded there is no reason why the code shown should not work.

Comment: the exception is coming in first line only           $(document).ready(function()

jQuery is loaded for sure as the same code is working fine in another solution.

Comment: Maybe the jquery code is loaded after this snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(function($) { //your code here })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <style>p { color:red; }</style>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

  $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");

});

  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <p>Not loaded yet.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Check your code. have you forgot to add Jquery or have add your function before calling the jQuery. 
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Had some extra handellers in web.config... Problem is resolved after removing the handellers. Rest everything was fine.